# Single application appbar to show back button when navigating throughout the application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I have my app.js file which looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment> 
        <AppBar/>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route render={({location}) => (
          <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
              key={location.key}
              timeout={100}
              classNames="someanimation"
            >
          <Switch location={location}>
               <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
               <Route exact path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
               <Route exact path="/customer/:id" component={CustomerPage} />
               <Route component={ErrorPage} />
             </Switch>
           </CSSTransition>
         </TransitionGroup>
       )} />
        </BrowserRouter>
     </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

This component has an appbar and a router with routes underneath. The point of the appbar being here is that the application then only has one appbar at all times throughout the application. Only the pages underneath change.

Inside my contact page I have a button that goes to a custom page with a param passed:

```
<Button component={Link} to={'/customer/' + customerID[99]}>
```

When the application goes to this customer page I want the appbar to show a back button. So I have to somehow notify the appbar to show this button and then also know which page to go back to (it should be the last page). I have googled some examples but I can't find one that fits this case.

Comment: Do you need something more than `history.back()`?

Comment: @estus I don't think so. I just need to it to go back to the page they came from. My problem is how to notify the appbar it is on a child page so that the back button appears and how for when the back button is pressed it knows which page it should go to. I should also note I am quite new to react and react router so I may be missing obvious things.

Comment: Use state in the app.js to show/hide pass the event to show the button to the contact us page and handle it from there.

Comment: @Justcode So the appbar is the parent component so how would it know what page it is on? Reading the react router docs, for example, this.props.location.pathname is only available to the child components and passing data between child to parent is not recommended according to the docs. My problem then seems to be how to notify the parent component what page it is on and to tell the parent exactly which page it is on

Comment: Where did you see passing props is not recommended? how will you inform parent about the changes and tell to show the button?

Comment: @Justcode How would I do this? I am confused about how to even pass a callback to a route?

Comment: The way this should be done depends on how this should work. You didn't describe that. Let's say a user goes to `example.com/contacts` and it's first page he/she browses. Should there be back button and where should it lead?

Comment: @estus No the back button should not appear in that situation. The back button should only appear when the user navigates deeper within the application.

Answer (score 0):

React router contains [`withRouter` higher-order component](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) that can provide relevant props to application bar component.

React router is powered by `history.js` library which is an abstraction over browser history API. While it can be used to navigate over browser history with `history.goBack()`, it won't work well with navigating over application alone because window history may contain other websites.

The component can look like this (a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ehefa1)) and should be a child of router component to get router props:

```
@withRouter
class AppBar extends Component {
  state = {
    locations: [this.props.location]
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
      if (action === 'REPLACE')
        return;

      this.setState({
        locations: [location, ...this.state.locations]
      })
    });
  }

  back = () => {
    const [location, ...locations] = this.state.locations;
    this.setState({ locations });
    this.props.history.replace(location);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {this.state.locations.length > 1 && <button onClick={this.back}>Back</button>}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

It keeps track on location changes and navigates through them. It would be more complex task to keep it in sync with browser history navigation buttons (back and forward).